# Trying to deploy a play framework application on a cloud service fails because of the way git handles symbolic links

Tags: git, deployment, playframework-2.0

Up until today we have used **symbolic links** extensively in order to have common source code among project in a **single place** and also be able to **edit or improve it very quickly**. The extra benefit was that we **did not have to compile** the common source code into any jar files. All worked because `play dist` did not have any issues with symbolic links.

When you want to **deploy on a cloud service** you must have a **git repository which includes all the files** even the ones that the symbolic links refer to, otherwise it will not compile on the cloud.

### Solution A

**Create a jar file for each package** of common source code. This is **really cumbersome**. We would not have access to edit the source code from inside the project and we would have to deal with compiling jar files each time after changing something. (unless intellij has an easy way to do it)

### Solution B

Copy entire folder with `cp -LR <source dir> <target dir>` command in order to **create a temporary dir with no symbolic links**. Keep over there, at the target dir, a seperate git repository to have it for deployment. For this one *We go by the moto that if the solution is not beautiful then the solution is wrong*

**Any other more elegant solution?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using git submodules: http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules if your "common code" is publicly (meaning without needing a private ssh key) accessible. Clever Cloud support them. I guess other cloud providers might support it too.

Comment: thanks! your solution have worked just fine. Git submodules gives a weird sense of flexibility. Hope it works well in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You did not give any information about the service you are using, but most of the times cloud solutions have a pre-build ( *or some similar* ) hook which will be triggered before the build starts. Using that hook you could create the symlinks before compilation starts.

Comment: We currently use a non-cloud solution, meaning that deployment is not performed through git. We just started testing cloud-services. Clever-cloud is one of them and as far as documentation goes there is no pre-build hook, only a post-build one. But still it would be somehow ugly to use it. Seems that trying to use intellij's advanced features to automate *Solution A* worths a try.

Comment: Its a strange thing that they don't have anything more that a post-build hook. Did you try to contact their support ? Maybe they missed to document it or they can give you a solution to your problem specific to their service.